# How does something get its name?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo you have all sorts of names for items and monsters. Note that I only play the german version of the game but I think it's kind of the same in english.

I often see items like "Schärpe des Bären" which would roughly translate to "Belt of the bear". Now all Items I found that had a "bear" in their name had vitality as a stat. But sometimes you find Items that don't fit into a certain pattern. Are these names completely random or are they fixed.

Also when it comes to monster names I often see something like "BlahBlah the destroyer". When it comes to weapons the first part is usually the name of the weapon (except for those special cases i mentioned) but  what determines both the "BlahBlah" and the "Destroyer" in a case like this (Random golden elite monsters). I just can't find a pattern here.

Comment: The pattern is only visible for magic items (blue) they show their affixes, rare items have more then just a single suffix/prefix and have a randomly generated name (combine a couple words from some list of options at random), behind the scens they still have those pre/suffixes though. Since this isn't even close to a full answer I'm commenting.

Comment: CEO of our company has a knack for knives. One of his recent purchases, a serrated clasp-knife, we used to call the "*Ripping Blade of the Director*" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blue items can have up to two affixes. Many of these have an associated modification that will be made to the item's name. Some affixes prefix the item's name with something, and others suffix the name. This, in fact, is how they came to be known as "affixes" in the first place. This is a holdover from the original Diablo and Diablo 2, where it worked similarly.

[Here's a database of all the affixes.](http://diablonut.incgamers.com/affixes)

For example, if you go to "Regen" (which is life per second), you notice that on an amulet or ring, depending on the level of the item, it will be a "Reptilian", "Salubrious", "Undying", or "Immortal" item. If you look at "Maximum Damage" for amulets/rings, you'll notice that it can be "of Wounding", "of Agony", "of Malice", etc., depending on the item's level again.

Taking this together, if you get a "Salubrious Amulet", you'll know it gives life per second. An "Amulet of Malice" will give you maximum damage. A "Salubrious Amulet of Malice" will give both.

Rare items also use these same affixes, but they don't affect the name of the item in the same way. I do think that the item affixes influence the name on rare items, but I don't think it's well-understood how exactly that works.

Comment: actually, Diablo 1

Comment: @kutschkem I only briefly played Diablo 1, so I didn't know. It makes sense, though.